# InfoPath 2013 web form doesn't open the browse dialog in the people picker control

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a user picker control, which when used in preview mode open a dialog to find users when I click on the browse button,
but do nothing when deployed on the SharePoint server.
If i type a user in the input box, the check names button is working and provide multiple choice when it's the case.
As the people picker control was modified in the new SharePoint 2013, could it be a side effect ?
Does anyone have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It worked once I enabled the ribbon in the form options.

Form Options -> Web Browser -> checked  Show InfoPath commands in Ribbon or toolbar

Answer (score -1):

Finally got the solution when you disable the ribbon the the browse button is also disabled to overcome this problem

- Create a new blank page or a wiki page.
- Insert a InfoPath Form WebPart and link this webPart to the desired form.
- Now after doing all the changes you can see that the form gets loaded and when you click the browse button it should function normally.
- If you want the same look of the form as it is when you open in it in new page or a tab, use a CEWP and add styles to disable unwanted controls like the navigation menus, search bar etc.,